# How to read, plot and convert WKT to table in R?

Tags: r, wkt

I have a [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) file with a few hundred `POLYGON((...,...,...))` entries. Is there an R package to read, plot and convert such data? I did not find anything explicit. Just want to avoid working with strings when there might be a more elaborate existing approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what packages that came up after a google search didn't work the way you needed them to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found two packages that bring me to a straightforward solution. Here's the code to extract the coordinates from a `POLYGON((...,...))` WKT type.

```
str="POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))"

library(rgeos)
# For this library you need to `sudo apt-get install libgeos++-dev` in Linux
test <-readWKT(str)
library(sp)
plot(test)
coords <- as.data.frame(coordinates(test@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]])) # Extracts coordinates of the polygon
```

EDIT: the aforementioned applies to a single string / WKT object. The following code can be applied to a WKT file, creating a list of matrices:

```
df <- read.table("yourfile.wkt",header = F, sep = "\t")
wow <- apply(df, 1, function(x) readWKT(as.character(x))) # Applies readWKT to every row of your df, i.e. to each WKT object
works = list()
for (i in 1:length(wow)) { 
  works[[i]] <- as.data.frame(coordinates(wow[[i]]@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]))
} # Loop populates a list with the coordinate matrices of each object of type polygon
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is a combination of the `sf` and `mapview` packages:

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)
str <- "POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))"
pnt <- st_as_sfc(str, crs = 4326)
mapview(pnt)
```

[image: map of results]

Answer (score 1):

one option is using `wellknown` which has a fxn to view the data with `leaflet`

```
library(wellknown)
str <- "POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))"
wktview(str)
```

[image]

and you can extract coordinates if you convert to geojson, e.g.,

```
wkt2geojson(str)$geometry$coordinates
```